# Can't connect to Dynamics 365 with Xrm.Tooling.Connector after 365 update

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Our organization uses Dynamics Online and this weekend received a major update from CRM 2016 (8.1) to 365 (8.2), and since then my apps can't connect using the Xrm.Tooling.Connector:

```
CrmServiceClient client1 = new CrmServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XrmPowerString"].ConnectionString);
```

On app.config I have the connection string

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Url=https://myorgname.crm.dynamics.com; Username=me@mydomain.com; Password=mypassword; AuthType=Office365" />
```

I get error:

> Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient Error: 2 : Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM

And also

> Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient Error: 2 : Source      : mscorlib
>   Method  : HandleReturnMessage
>   Date    : 14/08/2017
>   Time    : 01:46:02
>   Error   : An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.

Comment: It looks like everything is configured properly. Maybe check the versions of the SDK DLL's and make sure they're at v.8.2 as well.

Comment: I have the latest SDK with 8.2 on the bin folder BUT the sample project on it that I was debugging has the 8.0...can't believe spent hours trying to figure it out sure I had the latest. Thanks for making me double check.

Answer (score 3):

After researhing for a similar problem in dynamics 365 crm 9.0, we found that was caused by Security Protocol Type version.

Before instatiate your connection with CRM, ensure that your protocol version is TLS 1.2, adding the following code:
`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/235290

Comment: Thanks this answer helped me fix my problem.

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest DLLs (8.2).

If you are working with the sample projects within the SDK (my case), you MUST delete the content of the BIN folder and update all packages because even on the latest SDK, the samples are referring the old dll version 8.0.